# Module not found in python after installing in terminal

Tags: python, pip, splinter

This question has been asked a few times, but the remedy appears to complicated enough that I'm still searching for a user specific solution. I recently re-installed anaconda; now, after entering
     "`pip install splinter`" 
in the Terminal on my Mac I get the response: 
    "Requirement already satisfied: splinter in      /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: selenium>=2.53.6 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from splinter)"

But, I get the following error in python (Anaconda) after entering `import splinter`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    import splinter
ImportError: No module named splinter"

When I enter `which python` in the terminal, this is the output: "/usr/local/bin/python"

I am editing the question here to add the solution: `~/anaconda2/bin/pip install splinter`

Comment: Try `pip install -U splinter`

Comment: those are two different pythons. you are using the `pip` from your default python, but trying to import the package from anaconda

Answer (score 0):

those are two different pythons. you are using the pip from your default python, but trying to import the package from anaconda.

use

```
$ dirname `which python`
```

to see where the anaconda's `python` executable is, then see that folder for `pip`. now use this `pip` to install the package

Comment: Thank you. How do I "use this pip" to install the package? Just by setting the directory?

Comment: @bayrah either you can set the `$PATH` or you can simple run `/location/ro/anaconda/bin/pip install package` to use this pip to install the package

Comment: apologies, I found the solution with `~/anaconda2/bin/pip install splinter`

Answer (score 0):

1) Try uninstalling and the re install it:

```
pip uninstall splinter
```

2) Also manually delete splinter from "site-packages".

3)Also try this if problem still persists:

```
$ easy_install -m PACKAGE_name
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I uninstalled and reinstalled splinter many times but that didn't work. Then I typed `source activate (name of my conda environment)` and then did `pip install splinter`. It worked for me.